# 5 columns in a 6 column grid

Tags: susy-compass

I have a 6 column fixed width grid, but I'd like one particular "row" to have 5 columns instead, is that possible?

```
@import "susy";
@include border-box-sizing;

// The 1000px grid
$total-columns: 6;
$column-width: 150px;
$gutter-width: 20px;
$grid-padding: 0;

$container-style: static;
$container-width: 1000px;

$show-grid-backgrounds  : true;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure is. All Susy math is simply based on `columns / context`, so you can have as many columns as you want by lying to Susy about context.

```
$total-columns: 6;

.container {
  @include container;
  .tricky {
    @include span-columns(1,5); // tell Susy there are 5 columns, and suddenly there are.
  }
}
```

If you want to be more honest about it, or make 5 the default context for a larger chunk of code, you can simply wrap that code in `layout(5) { ... }` or `with-grid-settings(5) { ... }` and within that block `$total-columns == 5`.